# Page frontmatter assign to site frontmatter in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

How do I use a variable from the site _config.yml in a posts frontmatter?

I would like to do something like

```
---
github-id: site.github-id
---
```

However this literally sets it to the string "site.github-id".

Comment: You can't use liquid variable in front matter.

Comment: I gathered that, so what would be the neatest way of achieving this functionality?

Comment: What functionality? you'd like a user declared var to be displayed where? the posts title?

Comment: Yes that could be one example.

Comment: Unfortunately jeykll does not support liquid tags within front matter. You have a great work around though. Can you post it as an answer and mark it as correct to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this isn't currently possible due to limitations of Jekyll.

As a work around you can do something along these lines:

```
{% if page.github-id %}
 {{ page.github-id }}
{% else %}
 {{ site.github-id }}
{% endif %}
```